# A custom argument in graphene-django

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

How do I create a custom argument in GraphQL with graphene-django?

I currently have this configuration in my schema.py:

```
class Post(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = FeedPost
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = ['id']

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
         post = graphene.Node.Field(Post)

    def resolve_post(self, info, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.get('username')
        u = User.objects.get(username=username) 
        users_sources = FeedSource.objects.filter(user=u)
        return FeedPost.objects.filter(feed__feedsource__in=users_sources).annotate(
             source_title=F('feed__feedsource__title')
    )
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

But I have not been able to figure out how to make "username" a required argument in the actual GraphQL query on "post".

Comment: You have a choice of adding `username` as part of the `Post` input type, or as another separate argument to the query.  Since you don't show your `Post` model, it's not clear if username is already part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was supported before but i am using **graphene-django>=2.15,<2.16** and i can confirm the following syntax works as expected:

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    # Notice the username argument
    post = graphene.Field(Post, username=graphene.String(required=True, default=None))

    def resolve_post(self, root, info, username): # Notice: the username argument spelled exactly as before
        u = User.objects.get(username=username) 
        users_sources = FeedSource.objects.filter(user=u)
        return FeedPost.objects.filter(feed__feedsource__in=users_sources).annotate(
             source_title=F('feed__feedsource__title')
    )
```

GraphiQL also deals with it properly:
[image: GraphiQL with argument]